# Iterate over an IP list addresses

Tags: python-3.x, ip-address

I have a file containing different ip ranges with different subnets. I want now to get all the host from every ranges. So I used the [ipadress library](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ipaddress.html) with the `hosts()` function:

```
import subprocess
import ipaddress

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #host='8.8.8.8'
    #subprocess.run(["host", host])
    f=open('ip.txt', 'r')
    for line in f:
        #subprocess.run(["host", line])
        newLine=line+''
        newLine=newLine[:-1]#remove EOL
        #print(newLine)
        myList=ipaddress.ip_network(u''+newLine, False)#create the object
        list(myList.hosts())
        print(list)
        for i in list:
            subprocess.run(["host", i])
```

Currently my list is empty

`adriano@K62606:~/findRoute$ python3 workingWithMask.py 
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>`

and therefore I get the error:

```
<class 'list'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "workingWithMask.py", line 16, in <module>
    for i in list:
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

I precise, that the file is readed correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myList = ipaddress.ip_network(u''+newLine, False)
list(myList.hosts())
print(list)
for i in list:
```

You convert `myList.hosts()` to a list but throw it away, then printing the built-in **type** `list` then trying to iterate over it which makes no sense at all.

You have to keep the result of `list(...)` somewhere, then iterate over that.

Consider:

```
myList = list(ipaddress.ip_network(u''+newLine, False).hosts())
print(myList)
for i in myList:
    subprocess.run(["host", i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using list keyword which is a class.
try:

```
        ip_list=list(myList.hosts())
        print(ip_list)
        for i in ip_list:
            subprocess.run(["host", i])
```